# finding the most repeated number in an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Have to make program, where you input number, and program outputs most repeated digit in it, can't figure out have to do it. Tried some things, for me it works with static array, but I need dynamic, so I dont now what to do. 
Can someone help me?

Comment: What did you do so far to solve the problem.

Comment: Your title and body are mismatch

Comment: Telling us the things you tried don't work isn't informative at all; You don't have a specific question. Show an actual attempt, tell us how it failed *exactly* and we may be able to help.

Comment: Please post your source code or what ever you have tried with your remaining trouble! And please change the title to suit with content.

Answer (score 0):

- make an array in size of 10 (the number of digits)
- run over your original array and extract from each number all its digit, increase the value of your digit array for each digit you find.
  -find the maximal digit using the sight array.

You can upload a code if you want more help

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are served in real time digits [0-9] and you need a function that at any given time returns you the most frequent digit seen so far. A simplest solution would be just to have a hash map of [0-9] keys that maintains the number of times every digit is seen. When you need the most frequent digit you iterate over the 10 keys and return the one with the biggest count.